# Creating table of contents on the markdown file itself

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Is it possible to create table of contents in the markdown file itself with pandoc?

Answer (score 1):

It's sufficient to pass both, the `--toc` and `--standalone` options, to get a table of contents in the resulting markdown file.